# Visualization of data structures and indexes

Tags: tikz-pgf, data-structures, tikz-datavisualization

How can I make a similar visualization of data structures and indexes?
I went through the documentation of `TikZ` and could not find a way.

[image]

Comment: I think the easiest way would be multipart nodes. See section **17.3 Multi-Part Nodes** of the [Tikz manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), page 222.

Comment: I'd rather use Graphviz and its `record` shape. You can combine this with tikz using [dot2tex](http://alessandrovermeulen.me/2013/07/08/combining-graphviz-dot-and-tikz-with-dot2tex/). The bonus of Graphviz is that you do not have to care about the shape of the arrows but they are layed out automatically without crossing the nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a starting point for you using Multipart nodes. Feel free to ask if something is not clear.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={draw, text height=1.5ex},
    split/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1,draw,
        rectangle split horizontal=false,rectangle split part align=base},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, -{Latex}]

\node[split=2] (a1) at (0,0) {0x10ba8};
\node[split=4] (a2) at (4,1) {0xf7fc4380\nodepart{four}-1};
\node[split=4] (a3) at (4,-1) {0xf7fc44b8\nodepart{four}2};

\node[split=4] (a4) at (8,-3) {(nil)\nodepart{four}-1};

\draw (a1) -- (a2);
\draw (a1) -- (a3);

\path (a2.east) edge[out=-35,in=135] (a4.north west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to draw a path/arrow from a certain row to a certain row?

Comment: @zvisofer Yes. For example, `(a2.three east)` where "three" is the third part of the `a2` node.

Comment: is it possible to add a label to an adge/path?

Comment: @zvisofer Yes. Add to the path (you can add this right before the `;`), `node[midway] {}`. `midway` will put it in the middle. `pos=` will put it at a certain point from 0 to 1 (decimals), therefore `midway` = `pos=.5`. You can also add `left, right, above, etc` and `anchor=...` like any node.